# How do we know that the 3 vectors (M1b1, M1b2, M1b3) are not linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m71NN.png

In the last part of this question, the given solution is that 
M2M1(x) = M2( a1b1 + a2b2 +a3b3 ) , where two out of b1,b2,b3 are the basis vectors of the null space of M2, since K2 is a subspace of R1 and the dimension of K2 is 2.

Then, M2M1(x) = M2(a1b1) = a1(M2b1)

Any vector in the range space of M3 can hence be represented as a constant times one vector, so it has dimension 1.

My question is that in the first step, what if we do not choose two basis vectors out of the 3 to be from K2?

Then we would get

M2M1(x) = a1(M2b1) + a2(M2b2) + a3(M2b3), and M3 would have dimension 3 if these 3 vectors were linearly independent. But how do we know that these 3 vectors are not linearly independent?

Edit : My new question is how do we work out the dimension of M3 if we don't choose two basis vectors from K2.

Comment: Which three vectors are you talking about: $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ or their images under $M_2$?

Comment: You already know that $M_2$ has rank two, so it’s impossible for the images under $M_2$ of three vectors to be linearly independent.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about their images under M2. Why is it impossible? If M2 has rank 2, it just means that M2(x) = a1(b1) + a2(b2) for some linearly independent vectors b1,b2.

Comment: The dimension of a vector space is equal to the maximum number of linearly independent vectors.

Comment: I don't get it.. Rank 2 only implies you need 2 basis vectors to span the space.

Comment: It also means that *no* set of more than 2 vectors can be linearly independent. That comes directly from the definition of the dimension of a vector space.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. Thank you. I have a follow-up question; could you answer that?

Comment: Actually, what if we had Mx = a1b1 + a2b2 and My = (a1+1)b1 + (a2+1)b2 

These two vectors are linearly independent, but if we choose Mz = (a1+2)b1 + (a2+2)b2 , this set would be linearly independent as well..

Comment: The three are linearly dependent: $Mz=2My-Mx$.

Comment: Oh.. right. Sorry, silly of me.